# Loop through 3d array and add 2d slices N times

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a 3d array (lets name it a) with shape = (365, 28, 36). I consider this array as an 3d array with 365 pieces of 2d arrays (28,36) stacked on each other. I want now to loop through this 3d array and each 2d slice should be repeated 8 times and then stacked on each other. This means that I will end up with one array of size (2920, 28, 36). 2920 comes from 365*8.

My attempt so far has been this, but it does not work. Can anyone help with this problem?

```
l = []
for i in range(365):
    for j in range(28):
        for k in range(30):  
            l.extend(repeat(a[i,j,k], 8))
```

Comment: Can you please share a data sample of 3d array you talking about ?

Comment: Yes. The file I cal a can be found here. https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlJG9g1WlnmlhDC1WfgR1ljtI67E

Comment: "It does not work" is not a problem specification.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
newarray = []
for arr2d in oldarray:
    for _ in range(8):
        newarray.append(arr2d)
```

Arrays in python are actually lists, which mean they are variable length, 
so you can just do this. `oldarray` is your old 3d array, `newarray` is
your desired output, and arr2d is the 2d array inside `oldarray`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors in your code.  Also, I suspect that you want eight independent copies of the 2D data, rather than 8 pointers to the 2D slice (where if you change one value, you change them all).

Try this:

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = [
     [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']],
     [[4, 5, 6], ['@', '#', '$']],
     [[7, 8, 9], ['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
    ]

l = []
for slice in a:
    l.extend([deepcopy(slice) for _ in range(8)])

l[0][0][0] = "FLAG"
print l
```

IN the final print, note how only one location changes to the string "FLAG", rather than all 8 copies of that slice changing.